# Count number of times value appears consecutively in a row - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of rows where there are 24 columns each taking a value 0 or 1. I need to find the number of times a "1" appears consecutively first time in each row.  (I.e. if 1 appears twice in a row then we will add 1 to sum).

Example would be (putting in array format) - however not in array within table. will have x where count, o where no count.

[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[o, o, o, x, o, o, o, o, o, o, x, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, x, o, o, o, o]

result: "1" appears consecutively 3 total times.

Edit: I don't necessarily need to have the value 0, I could also use "" (blank) in place of 0 - thus potentially opening up the use of countif?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
=AND(A1=1,B1=1)+COUNTIFS(A1:W1,0,B1:X1,1,C1:Y1,1)
```

We want to count where the there is a pattern of `0,1,1` hence the equal size but offset ranges.  It will count where the pattern matches.  We also want to count if `A1` and `B1` both equal `1` because it should be positive but does not meet the pattern.

[image]

Comment: Looks surprisingly simple - can you please explain why we use three different ranges in the ```COUNTIFS```?

Comment: Ok so what if I wanted to have the max count be 4 - and if 4 has not been reached yet then we will want to turn on the counter for "1" that has "0"s on both sides ([0, 1, 0])

Comment: @ZacharyWyman that is a different question.

Comment: This is true - I will ask a follow up question, but I'm assuming it can be done by creating a counter column then if not 4 - add argument.

Comment: Sadly cannot ask another question for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```
=(26-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(0,A1:Y1),"011","")))/3
```

Note: `CONCAT()` is available from Excel 2019 onwards only.