# Count number of times "1" appears more than twice in a row and if max count is less than 4 - include "1" where no consecutives - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Follow up question to [Count number of times value appears consecutively in a row - Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67064262/count-number-of-times-value-appears-consecutively-in-a-row-excel)

I want to count the number of "1"'s that appear more than once consecutively in a row - and if max count for that row is less than 4, then also count 1's with no consecutives.

[image]

Below output is correct until single "1" which is not counted.
Countif formula is `=AND(E5=1, F5=1) + COUNTIFS(E5:Z5, "", F5:AA5, 1, G5:AB5, 1)` which recognizes consecutive "1"s. If row 3 had a single 1 at the beginning, its value would be 3 because counter (bold) is only 2.

Comment: Include them all or only enough to reach 4?

Comment: Only enough to reach 4

Comment: In your original question you gave the following example" `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]`, the total count is 3 which is less than 4, so could you please advise what would be the desired count based on your new requirement? Could you please in your example include a couple different scenarios and the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=AND(E1=1,F1=1)+COUNTIFS(E1:AA1,"",F1:AB1,1,G1:AC1,1)+MAX(MIN(4-(AND(E1=1,F1=1)+COUNTIFS(E1:AA1,"",F1:AB1,1,G1:AC1,1)),(E1=1)+COUNTIFS(E1:AA1,"",F1:AB1,1,G1:AC1,"")+AND(AB1="",AC1=1)),0)
```

[image]